# How to turn number into time format for JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp, time-series

A really basic way to turn the following into a JS formatted date that can be processed by plugins that need it in Javascript timestamps format. So hours and minutes are what the input includes.

```
// Hours 
  var hour = parseInt($('#hour').val(), 10);
// Mins
  var min = parseInt($('#min').val(), 10);
// Time of Day
  var tod = $('#tod').val();
```

I'm trying to get these values to work with this flot chart plugin.

https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data

Comment: Do you just want to pass those values into `var dt = new Date(here)`, then `console.log(dt.getTime())`? See the JavaScript Date Object to see what formats are accepted. You may have to add some numbers, which, if they're left out can be gotten using the Date Object and its methods.

Comment: @PHPglue I'd like to pass all of these into something that outputs the timestamp.

Comment: @PHPglue Sorry I realize I've given not enough information. 

The values being entered by the user using drop downs.

So for hours it's 1-12.
Mins 00, 15, 30, 45.
Time of day 'am' or 'pm'.

So I'm taking the strings, turning into int and now I want the time stamp value to work with the graph.

Comment: Well, pass in the values according to the correct `Date` Object format: w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp . You may have to do some calculations.